# ajax php request to web service

Tags: php, ajax, web-services

I need to write a php code using ajax to get a respond from http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/FahrenheitToCelsius webserver. below is the code which will post request and get the respond. since it is a post request the site get refreshed. without refreshing i need the respond.I dont know how to do it in ajax. please help me. thanks alot.

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['Fahrenheit'])&&$_POST['Fahrenheit']!=null) {
    $out = print_name($_POST['Fahrenheit']);
    }
    else {
     print_form();
    }

    function print_name($name) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $far = 'Fahrenheit='.$name;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx     /FahrenheitToCelsius");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$far);

        // http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        echo 'It is: '.$server_output;
        return $server_output;
    }


    function print_form() {
      echo '
        <form method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Fahrenheit to Celsius:</td>
        <td>
        <input class="frmInput" type="text" size="30" name="Fahrenheit">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">
         <input name="cel" type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
         </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
      ';
    }
```

please help me.

Comment: working that way you need to reload your page for getting values of the post, you can print the form to show it always by removing if condition, or you can put PHP part of this file to another file and use ajax

Comment: @Akam ok but i dont know ajax. can you please help me to do it. i dont know how to pass values and how to get the respond and view amoung those files. thanks for the support

Comment: You clearly are not meeting the requirement to have a minimal understanding of the question being asked.  Try to research and learn AJAX, as SO is not really intended to answer requests like "teach me AJAX".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is kind of "please do my own homework", my answer points to a good site were you can do your own assignments: http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call

What you want to do is to use xmlHTTPRequest() object in a javascript to post data to a webserver and read the response.

The page linked above has a broken link to a demo, here is the right one: http://ajaxify.com/run/xmlHtttpRequestCall/

and the source of the page is very interesting, for example please consider this snippet:

```
function createXMLHttpRequest() {
  try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
  alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
  return null;
}
var xhReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open("GET", "sumGet.php?figure1=5&figure2=1", false); //here method of sending data and server page where to send to
    xhReq.send(null);
    var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
    $("response").innerHTML = serverResponse;
```